# Odoo - How add a field to view from another wizard model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I want the use a field from wizard to my form view.

Let me explain with code:

```
class CancelAppointmentWizard(models.Model):
    _name = "cancel.appointment.wizard"
    _description = "Cancel Appointment Wizard"

    reason = fields.Text(string="Reason")
```

and i want the show this "**reason**" field inside of some form views.

```
<record id="view_hospital_appointment_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hospital.appointment.form</field>
        <field name="model">hospital.appointment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="reason"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

but of course this give me error like

```
hospital.appointment don't have a field like reason.
```

How can show this field ?
I tried to make a dummy code, i hope i was able to explain my problem.

Comment: You need to add a text field named `reason` on `hospital.appointment` model to save the reason value from the wizard

Answer (score 0):

I assume the wizard is called from the `view_hospital_appointment_form`. And in the wizard view let say there is a `button` tag with `name` attribute, which is this attribute associated to python method in your wizard class.

Wizard view

```
<record id="view_cancel_appointment_wizard_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">cancel.appointment.wizard.form</field>
    <field name="model">cancel.appointment.wizard</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            …
            …
            <footer>
                <button name="action_ok" string="Ok" type="object"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Python method

```
def action_ok(self):
    ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids')

    hospital_appointment = self.env['hospital.appointment'].browse(ids)
    hospital_appointment.reason = self.reason

    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

Comment: That's probably the answer to the next step: how to set a value from a wizard to a record. But the error message of the question clearly states, that there is not field `reason` on model `hospital.appointment`. So probably adding the field to that model should be the first step? ;-)

Comment: Yes you're correct @CZoellner. We need to add `reason` field in the `hospital.appointment` model first.